# Given $u,v,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, is there $L \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $u,v,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy:

**(1)** $vmn \neq 0$ (namely, perhaps $u=0$, but each of $\{v,m,n\}$ is non-zero).

**(2)** $u+m$ is odd.

**(3)** $v+n$ is odd.

> Is it possible to find $1 < L \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the greatest common divisor of $u+Lm$ and $v+Ln$ is $1$?

It seems to me that the answer should be positive, but I do not know how to prove this.
Perhaps it is better to first concentrate on the case $u=0$, and then consider arbitrary $u \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about $u,v,m,n$ all even?

Comment: You are right, in that case there is NO such $L$ (the greatest common divisor is at least $2$). I will change my question a little.

Comment: Do you also want to rule out $u = v > 1$ and $m = n$?

Comment: Good, I also want to rule out $m=n$. I do not mind to have $u=v \geq 1$; do you have a counterexample for $u=v$?

Comment: Suppose $u,v,m,n$ are all divisible by some prime $p>2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions as given allow the case where $u,v,m,n$ are all divisible by some prime $p>2$, for example $(u,m,v,n) = (5,10,15,20)$. This would mean that for any choice of $L$, $g:=\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln)$ is divisible by $p$ (and so $g\ne 1$).

You could also have the case where $(u,m,v,n) = (ka,kb,\ell a, \ell b)$ leading to $g$ being divisible by $a+Lb$ - for example, $(u,m,v,n) = (15,20,21,28)$.

If the conditions were changed to:
**(1)** $vmn\ne 0$
**(2)** $\gcd(u,m)=1$
**(3)** $\gcd(v,n)=1$
then I think there will be a choice of $L$ that gives $g=1$.

Comment: Please, can I ask you a question? I wish to write a paper, with a result based on your idea ("if the conditions were changed to..."). Is it possible to just cite your answer, or do you think you should be a co-author? (I guess this depends on how much you think you contributed to my paper).

Comment: Sure, you can just cite this answer. I haven't yet done the work to show that the suggested conditions are sufficient. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will update you as soon as I will have a plausible version of my paper (it may take a few days or weeks). Perhaps I will post it first on vixra or peerj https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37976/what-are-pre-print-repositories-for-math-and-physics-alternative-to-arxiv so that you can see my work and make a final decision about your contribution. (Maybe you will  add ideas to my paper and if so, then obviously you will be a co-author). Please see also my recent question on MO: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3827/using-ideas-found-in-mo-and-mse-in-a-paper