# Specific $u,v,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, for which there exists $L \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

After reading the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811373/given-u-v-m-n-in-mathbbn-is-there-l-in-mathbbn-such-that-gcdulm/2811543#2811543), I wish to ask the following question:

Let $u,v,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy:

**(1)** $m \neq n$.

**(2)** $vmn \neq 0$ (namely, perhaps $u=0$, but each of $\{v,m,n\}$ is non-zero).

**(3)** $\gcd(u,m)=1$.

**(4)** $\gcd(v,n)=1$.

> Is it possible to find $1 < L \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the $\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln)=1$?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** After reading the answer, if I am not wrong, the following claims are true:

**(i)** If $m < n$, then we can dismiss of condition $(3)$ (condition $(4)$ yields $v+Ln$, for large enough $L$, is prime).

**(ii)** If $m < n$, and we know that condition $(3)$ is satisfied but do not know if condition $(4)$ is satisfied or not, then for large enough $L$, $\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln) \in \{1,p\}$, for some prime $p$.

Comment: You did not exclude the case with  $u=v$ and $m=n$.

Comment: Truly, I do not mind that $u=v$, but I forgot to mention that I prefer to assume that $m \neq n$; does it matter?

Comment: If you meant $m\neq n$, it should not matter. See my answer. More precisely, $|m|\neq |n|$ would be better.

Comment: Good. Thank you very much. If I would like to assume that $m \neq n$, then we can delete from your answer "or, $0 < m=n$ and $0 < u < v$? (you dealt with two disjoint cases, right?).

Comment: Yes, I will delete the part.

Comment: You do not need to. (I did not mention $m \neq n$).

Comment: ok, I will add $m \neq n$ to my question.

Comment: Your edit after the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $0<m<n$.

There is $L_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$0<u+Lm < v+Ln$$for any $L\geq L_0$.

By [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), there is $L\geq L_0$ such that $v+Ln=p$ for some prime number $p$.

Then this prime $p$ cannot divide $u+Lm$.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice! It (= Dirichlet's theorem) looks like the result I was looking for.

Comment: I have just added 'Edit', and it would be nice if you will confirm that my two claims are true. (I am 99.99% sure that they are true, by the same arguments presented in your answer).

Comment: Please, I have a question to you: If I wish to write a paper and use your answer as a tool in a proof to my result, would you agree that I just cite your answer or do you think you should be a co-author? (I guess it depends on the specific paper I write, how much you think you contribute). Thank you.

Comment: Citing it will be good. I'd be happy to read your paper. Let's communicate in email: Mine is 707107@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much! I will email you as soon as I will have a plausible version of my paper (it may take a few days or weeks). Please see my last two comments in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811373/given-u-v-m-n-in-mathbbn-is-there-l-in-mathbbn-such-that-gcdulm?noredirect=1#comment5914211_2811543