# An application to Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The current question asks for the existence of $L \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the conditions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811373/given-u-v-m-n-in-mathbbn-is-there-l-in-mathbbn-such-that-gcdulm/2811543#2811543) and an additional condition;
I hope that it is still possible to find $L \in \mathbb{N}$ (= hopefully, the additional condition will not cause too much trouble).

Let $u,v,m,n,\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ satisfy: 
$m < n$; $\gcd(u,m)=1$; $\gcd(v,n)=1$.

> Is it possible to find $L \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the following two conditions are satisfied:
>
> **(i)** $\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln)=1$.
>   **(ii)** $\epsilon \nmid u+Lm$ and $\epsilon \nmid v+Ln$.

**A special case:** I do not mind to first concentrate on the special case where $\epsilon$ is a prime number (though I slightly prefer $\epsilon$ to be any natural number).

**Almost an answer:** According to the above mentioned question, it is possible to find $L \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u+Lm < v+Ln$ and $v+Ln$ is a prime number,
so **(i)** is satisfied (= the gcd of a prime number and a smaller number is $1$), but it seems that **(ii)** may not be satisfied: Although we can take $L$ large enough such that (in addition to $v+Ln$ being prime, we also have) $\epsilon < v+Ln$, so $\epsilon \nmid v+Ln$ (because $v+Ln$ is prime), but unfortunately it may happen that $\epsilon | u+Lm$.

Notice that making the smaller of the two, $u+Lm$, a prime $p$, may be worse, because in that case even condition **(i)** may not be satisfied, since now $\gcd(u+Lm,v+Ln) \in \{1,p\}$.

**A remark:** Please see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311395/almost-simultaneous-dirichlets-theorem-on-arithmetic-progressions).

**Edit:** In view of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930958/concerning-dicksons-conjecture), I think that I will further assume  that $\epsilon \geq 3$.

**Edit 2:** Please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932464/existence-of-m-in-m-subsetneq-mathbbn-such-that-p-nmid-abm-p-prime/2932471#2932471); if we wish to apply its answer to my current question, then (if I am not wrong) we will obtain that a positive answer to my current question may depend on $v,n$ and the set of natural numbers which make $v+Ln$ a prime number. (But perhaps a different approach may yield a positive answer to my current question?).

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I am not wrong, if $\epsilon \neq 2$ is a prime number, then by the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930958/concerning-dicksons-conjecture ($p>k$), we see that (ii) can be satisfied (although I am not sure if (ii) can be satisfied with (i)).

Comment: Minor note: of course $\epsilon$ cannot be $1$.  The case where $\epsilon$ is prime is the only one worth considering (if $3 \nmid n$ then automatically $12 \nmid n$).  Perhaps you meant to say that $(\epsilon, u+Lm) =1$?

Comment: Thanks for your good comment, which clarifies my question. Yes, if $\epsilon$ is not prime then I meant that condition (ii) will say that $\gcd(\epsilon,u+Lm)=1$ and $\gcd(\epsilon,v+Ln)=1$. I do not mind, as a first step, to assume that $\epsilon$ is prime, if that simplifies things. Please do you think that there is a positive answer to my question?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the answer is yes for odd $\epsilon\ge 3$.  I think it can be done without even using Dirichlet’s theorem.  The key is to restrict the set of primes $p$ which could possibly divide both $u+Lm$ and $v+Ln$.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to think about your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the OP edit, we need to take $\epsilon > 1$ odd as at least one of $1+L$, $2+3L$ is always even.

Suppose $p$ is a prime divisor of $(u+Lm, v+Ln)$.  Then it also divides the integer combination $n(u+Lm)-m(v+Ln) = nu - mv$, which is a constant independent of $L$.

So the only possible primes dividing the gcd are the divisors of $nu-mv$.  Note that the constraints preclude this quantity from being zero (otherwise $n/v = m/u$ with both fractions being in lowest terms, which contradicts $m\ne n$), so there are only finitely many such primes.  Likewise there are only finitely many primes dividing $\epsilon$.  Let $P$ be the largest of all primes in either category.

By the argument of the related question, for any prime $p\ge 3$, we can choose a congruence class for $L$ mod $p$ such that $p \nmid m+Lu$ and $p \nmid n + Lv$.  For $p=2$, we can’t guarantee the same, but we can at least ensure one of $m+Lu$ and $n+Lv$ is odd by fixing the parity of $L$.

Combining all these congruences for all primes $p\le P$, we get a congruence class for $L$ (modulo the primorial of $P$) which ensures $(m+Lu, n+Lv) = 1$ (recall that primes above $P$ can’t divide the gcd), as well as the $\epsilon$ condition.

I feel there is probably a more efficient construction based on a similar question I have seen years before.  Maybe someone can provide it.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! The 'trick' of considering $n(u+Lm)-m(v+Ln)$ is very nice.

Comment: The same trick is frequently used in the more general context of detecting the possible values of the gcd of two integer polynomials.

Comment: Thank you. Please, is it possible, in addition to conditions (i) and (ii), to guarantee a third condition: (iii) $v+Ln$ is prime?

Comment: @user237522 Certainly, since we have an entire residue class to work within.  First let’s be a little more careful around $p=2$ and specify that $v+Ln$ is chosen to be odd.  We also enrich $P$ to cover any prime factors of $v$.  Then replaying the construction gives a residue class for $L$ such that $v+Ln$ never has small prime divisors, including the divisors of $v$.  Then Dirichlet’s theorem guarantees that some (infinitely many) $L$ will produce a prime value.

Comment: I understand that by Dirichlet's theorem we can find $T$ (and then also every $S > T$ which is obtained by Dirichlet's theorem) such that $v+Tn$ is prime and larger than a given prime (= the maximum of some finite set of primes). What I do not understand is that if we have a residue class of $L$, then why there exist members of that residue class that are also obtained by Dirichlet's theorem? (I really apologize if I am taking too much of your time if I am missing something trivial which I should have understood myself).

Comment: @user237522 Not a bad question.  The residue class takes the form $L = Ax + B$ for some constants $A,B$.  Plugging this into the linear form $v + Ln$ gives us a new linear form $(v+nB) + (An)x$.  It then becomes a question of whether the new coefficients are relatively prime.  If they were not, then some prime divisor of $An$ would divide every value of $(v+nB) + (An)x$, but we chose $A,B$ so that this never happens.  Except that I should have included the divisors of $n$, not $v$ in the amendment of $P$ in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: Based on this question, I can show that if $(p,q)$ is a counterexample to the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture, then $\gcd(\deg(p),deg(q)) \geq 27$. If I am not wrong, it is now known that $\gcd(\deg(p),\deg(q)) \geq 16$. You can be a co-author in my paper, if you like. If not, then at least I will refer to this MSE question and mention your name in the ackonwledgements. Anyway, please contact me by email: user237522mse@gmail.com

Comment: @user237522 Thanks for your comment, just sent a reply.

Comment: Thanks for your generosity. I have just sent you a reply.